# how use tippy .js in tooltip in jquery

Tags: jquery, tooltip, tippyjs

I want to use some classes in tippyjs to change the codes when those classes are called but I don't know how to use them

```
new Tippy('.tooltip.fade.bottom.in {}', {
    position: 'top',
    animation: 'scale',
    arrow: 'true',


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

As stated in the [Tippy JS documentation](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/creating-tooltips/):

1. Make sure you've included these links in your HTML
2. Then, initialize tippy by calling the function `tippy($('#someElementId'))` substitute #someElementId with your HTML element

```js
tippy('button');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@5/dist/backdrop.css" />
<button data-tippy-content="Tooltip">Text</button>
```

Comment: why i can't use as `tippy('button', {
animation: 'scale'
});`